# Refer to variable by name (not by position) when running sql script with SQLPlus

Tags: sqlplus

I know that with SQLPlus I can do this way:

```
@script1.sql 'a' 'b'
```

text of script1.sql:

```
select &1, &2 from dual;
```

result

```
a b
```

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
@script1.sql var1 = 'a'  var2 ='b'
```

text of script1.sql:

```
select &var1, &var2 from dual;
```

and have the same result?

Comment: Since a negative answer would not count as an answer, I guess, a comment only, then... No, there's no way to pass arguments to sqlplus scripts via named notation, only positional... as is the case with Windows' batch scripts and *nix sh/bash scripts, too.

Comment: Thanks. I found that I can use `define var1 = &1` at the top of script1. So it solved part of my problem.

Comment: Yes, that's the usual way of making the positional arguments more sane.